# Restoring window after "Hide window"

Tags: shortcut-keys

Is it possible to create a shortcut for undoing "Hide window?

That is restoring the most recently hidden (minimized) window.

(Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> will bring you back to the last minimized window.

That keyboard combination switches you through the windows in a reversed order. Your minimized window is last in the list, so will be recalled. This works only on a per-desktop base. So if you already moved to another desktop, you will need to switch back to the desktop where the hidden window resides.

If you use the regular window switcher instead of the application switcher, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will do the same thing, across desktops if the window switcher is set to list windows on all desktops.